# Why can't `lsof` report some open port's information?

Tags: socket, lsof, port

I am running this with the IP address of the same machine:

```
$ nmap -p0-65535 192.168.1.198

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-20 10:13 EDT
Nmap scan report for olive.fios-router.home (192.168.1.198)
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Not shown: 65526 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
111/tcp   open     rpcbind
139/tcp   open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
2049/tcp  open     nfs
5900/tcp  filtered vnc
41441/tcp open     unknown
43877/tcp open     unknown
44847/tcp open     unknown
55309/tcp open     unknown
```

Does "open" mean "listening"?

Why can't the following `lsof` report some open port's information? Thanks.

```
$ sudo lsof -i :2049
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:2049
$
```

Comment: In this case the second answer is correct. That's because nfs isn't userspace process https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97764/85046

Comment: What is NFS? NFS stands for Network File System. You can find more on wikipedia or in manual pages nfs(5)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System
https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs

Comment: nfs isn't userspace process. what is it instead?

Comment: Kernel space. Try to execute `ps -ef | grep nfs` kernel processes. They are displayed wrapped in [brackets]. There's already an answered question here:  [https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45899/85046](Why is Linux NFS server implemented in the kernel as opposed to userspace?)